# The conclusion of the test

Tags: riddle

> If I'm real, you want me.
>   If I'm not, I'm a lie.
>   If I'm real, you'll eat me.
>   If I'm not, I'm batter.
>
> You might eat me raw, though not healthy.
>   You might eat me baked, still not healthy.
>   You might want me now, but it's not the time.
>   You might want to celebrate, it's finally time.

What am I?

Hint:

> The achievement in one game for making me is a reference to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> A cake?

If I'm real, you want me.

> You want cake if it's real

If I'm not, I'm a lie.

> "Cake is a lie" is a phrase from Portal

If I'm real, you'll eat me.

> You can eat cake if it's real

If I'm not, I'm batter.

> If it's not made, it's cake batter

You might eat me raw, though not healthy.

> Raw cake batter is not healthy (raw eggs)

You might eat me baked, still not healthy.

> Cake is sweet and not necessarily healthy

You might want me now, but it's not the time.

> People don't randomly eat cake at random times

You might want to celebrate, it's finally time.

> Cake is eaten at celebrations

Hint:

> The achievement in one game for making me is a reference to another. 
>  In Minecraft, the achievement for making cake is "The Lie", which is a Portal reference.

Comment: I guess I need to wait 15 minutes from making the question before I can mark an answer as correct XD

Answer (score 3):

> It's cake!
>  Explanation: *If I'm real, you want me.* Cake is a delicious treat, and probably something that you'd want. *If I'm not, I'm a lie.* This is a reference to "the cake is a lie", a cultural reference. (EDIT: Portal) *If I'm real, you'll eat me.* Cakes are edible! *If I'm not, I'm batter.* An uncooked cake is simply a bowl of batter. *You might eat me raw, though not healthy.* One can eat uncooked cake batter, but can face certain health risks, such as *Salmonella*. *You might eat me baked, but still not healthy.* Cakes generally contain a large amount of saturated fat and sugar, which isn't great for you. *You might want me now, but it's not the time.* Those on a diet have to restrain from eating delicious foods such as cake. *You might want to celebrate, it's finally time.* Cakes are often the most looked forward to part of a celebration, such as a birthday.

The hint:

> Baking a cake in the game Minecraft is a reference to Portal. (The achievement is known as "A Lie".)

The title:

> In the game Portal, a cake is promised to the character Chell for completing a test.

Comment: Great answer! Think I just nipped you!

Comment: I'm afraid El-Guest was more specific in his answer, and he explained the hint. Well done, though!

Comment: Darn. Good job, @El-Guest! I saw you post as I was typing the last sentence.